# Removing all position constraints for a XAML element

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am building a UWP app. I am using a Rectangle XAML element for which I have specified a positioning attribute- RelativePanel.RightOf() in the XAML code. Now on clicking a specific button, I need to move the Rectangle from its original place to the left of some other control. So on receiving the Click event I use the property RelativePanel.SetLeftOf() to move it.

XAML code-

```
    <StackPanel>
        <RelativePanel Height="50" Width="200">
            <Rectangle x:Name="_redRect" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Red" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="_blueRect" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Blue" RelativePanel.RightOf="_redRect"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="_greenRect" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Green" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
        </RelativePanel>
        <Button x:Name="_switch" Click="OnSwitchClicked">Switch</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

C# code-

```
    private void OnSwitchClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RelativePanel.SetLeftOf(_blueRect, _greenRect);
    }
```

But this does not solve my problem. The _blueRect seems to be placed in the middle of the _redRect and _greenRect. This is probably because the first constraint RelativePanel.LeftOf = "_redRect" has not been removed. How do I remove that constraint through code?

Also is there any way through which all positioning constraints can be removed together?

Comment: Show and Tell.  Show us what you have tried (meaning you have made an effort to actually CODE what you need), what you have encountered, specifically.  ...and... we will tell answers :)

Comment: @Epistaxis done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is probably because the first constraint RelativePanel.LeftOf = "_redRect" has not been removed. How do I remove that constraint through code?

If you want to remove the `RelativePanel.RightOf="_redRect"`, you could use the same way to set the `RelativePanel.RightOf` to null in code.

```
private void OnSwitchClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RelativePanel.SetLeftOf(_blueRect, _greenRect);
    RelativePanel.SetRightOf(_blueRect, null);
}
```

[image]